# How do you pull a list of all scheduled jobs in Windows 2012 Server Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012

I've been tasked with running a daily report that looks at all our jobs scheduled to run on that day, and checks to see if they have successfully ran or not.  For now we are running on Windows 2008 Server, and have our jobs scheduled through the Task Scheduler.  I'm definitely not a Windows developer, so I'm wondering if it is possible to pull the information I'm looking for through `PowerShell` or some other tool?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following PowerShell command for scheduled tasks

```
   Get-ScheduledTask | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
```

This will give you the information like when was the last time a task was run and what was the output etc. To make it look more organised or to select only information you require you can do the following:

```
  Get-ScheduledTask | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Select TaskName,TaskPath,LastRunTime,LastTaskResult
```

Comment: Just to save some folks some time: `Get-ScheduledTask` is  a PS 6 cmdlet. I think the best the O.P. could do is install PS 5 on his win server 2012 machine

Comment: here good post about this: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/01/17/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-document-scheduled-tasks/